# Execute a cmd.exe command with a delay from a WinForms app

Tags: c#, .net, file, cmd, process

I'm working on a very simple desktop app that needs to be auto-updateable by itself, I can't use ClickOnce since the instalation path must be always the same (i.e. C:/app/myapp.exe).

My app checks for new available versions correctly, download files in a temporary folder, and after a delay of N seconds it deletes its own .exe file and replace it for the new one.

I'm using System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo for my purpose. Here is a simplified version of my **working** code (please note I use a lot of choice commands in order to keep console open and can check results...):

```
ProcessStartInfo testProcess = new ProcessStartInfo();
testProcess.Arguments = 
                    "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 5 & cd \"" + "C:/myapp" + "\" " + 
                    "& del \"" + "hello.txt" + "\" & choice";
testProcess.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
testProcess.ErrorDialog = true;
testProcess.CreateNoWindow = false;
testProcess.FileName = "cmd.exe";
Process.Start(testProcess);
```

I can correctly delete files, move, replace it, etc, etc. The problem comes when I try to start the new .exe with the same arguments (args) of the current execution. The code is very similar, it only changes the cmd command I'm using (start) in order to run the new app, here is the full code for that part:

```
ProcessStartInfo testProcess = new ProcessStartInfo();
procesoTest.Arguments =
                "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 5 & cd \"" + datos.RUTA_INSTALACION_LOCAL + "/app" + "\" " +
                "& \"" + "gestion.exe " + string.Join(" ", args) + "\" & choice";
testProcess.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
testProcess.ErrorDialog = true;
testProcess.CreateNoWindow = false;
testProcess.FileName = "cmd.exe";
Process.Start(testProcess);
```

The .exe exists at C:/myapp/myapp.exe and it runs correctly, but ignoring the args parameters. How could I set it?

Comment: You are running a high level programming language which does not require the involvement of cmd.exe. Cmd.exe is not needed to run choice.exe. Choice.exe is not needed anyhow, as it has only one option which is invoked regardless of the user accepting within five seconds. cmd.exe is not needed to delete a file or to run an executable file, even with a defined working directory.

Comment: Please read the full text, I need to delete and replace the CURRENT executable, so before closing it, I set the command with a delay, if I use a thread and my executable is closed the thread never run

Comment: You do not need to use choice.exe to add a delay of five seconds either. Timeout.exe is designed especially for that task, and that also does not require to be run by cmd.exe.

Comment: wow, timeout will help me, thanks, now I'm trying to write a .bat with all comands and run it instead of launching N Process.Start(), I can't find any other way if I want to delete the current exe, replace it and run it again

Answer (score 1):

Run `start /?` then you will know the quoted argument after the start command is the title. If you want to run myapp.exe, either remove the quotation marks or add a title argument before myapp.exe.

```
"& start " + "myapp.exe" + " & choice";
"& start \"MYAPP\" \"" + "myapp.exe" + "\" & choice";
```

Comment: That solution is almost the same that I had, the problem was I was using myapp.exe as FileName, by using cmd.exe now it is working fine, but I have edited the post since I have a different problem with the args of the program. Thanks anyway dude.

Comment: "start" disappears in your update.

Comment: That's because it is working witouth using start. but I can't invoke the program with the args, neither using start